# Calculating Area within a circle given radius and another length. (Topic = Trigonometric Function)

Tags: trigonometry

[Here is the question from Margaret Grove Maths in Focus.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ssizd.png)

I have tried to answer it. I am not sure what to apply here, given only 2 seemingly unrelated values. 
Here is the question:

The dartboard above has a radius
of 23 cm. The shaded area has a
height of 7 mm. If a player must
hit the shaded area to win, find
(a) the area of the shaded part, to
the nearest square centimetre

Comment: I have tried to answer but I don't know what to do!!! I can't calculate the area of a segment, there's no angle. I am only given one value for the shaded area (perpendicular height) so how am i meant to do anything

Comment: @JamesCashel I think it's fair to assume that each of the segments has the same angle.

Comment: @AlexB. oh, so 360/20? ok :) thanks!

Comment: @JamesCashel Yep! And you don't even need to know the exact value of the angle -- you can just find the area of the circle and divide by $20$. Then repeat and subtract.

Comment: @AlexB. thank you so much :) i am a bit brain dead in maths today.. i appreciate  your help!!

Answer (score -1):

First find the area of circle including the shaded part,

$(let) circle = \pi * (23)^2$

Then, find the area of circle other than the shaded part,

$(let) circle2 = \pi * (22.3)^2$

At last subtract them and divide by 20 and thats your answer